# Importing multiple images

Tags: terraform

I've multiple images that are required to be imported to the cloud using terraform. There is a limit for concurrent image importing is set to 3.

Is there any possibility to **import the images serially**.

I mean importing images one at a time
(Ex: image1 import ->  image2 will wait image1 completion -> image3 will wait for image2 completion)

We have depends_on but it's doesn't fit here.

Terraform code:

```
local { 
host_images = { 
 image1 = "source_uri
 image2 = "source_uri
 image3 = "source_uri
 image4 = "source_uri
 image5 = "source_uri
  }
} 


resource oci_core_image test_image {
     for_each = local.host_images

  compartment_id = var.compartment_id
  display_name   = each.key

  image_source_details {
    source_type = "objectStorageUri"
    source_uri  = each.value
  }
}
```

Comment: You could probably try with https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/apply#parallelism-n and set it to be equal to 3 when running `terraform apply`.

Answer (score 0):

When a remote system imposes a constraint such as a concurrency limit, in Terraform architecture it's typically the responsibility of the provider to handle that limit, such as by using a mutex or semaphore in its own process to limit the concurrency. If the limit you've described is something inherent to OCI (as opposed to something special about your particular usage) then it may be worth raising this as an issue with the provider developer team to see if the provider can handle this better.

In the meantime though, to handle this without changes to the provider your two main options would be:

- Declare each image explicitly using a separate `resource "oci_core_image" "test_image"` block, instead of using `for_each`.

  Dependencies in Terraform are between resources rather than resource instances, and so declaring it in that way would allow you to use `depends_on` to force a particular ordering of those operations. `for_each` declares a number of resource instances that are all, from Terraform's perspective, independent of one another and thus deployable concurrently.
- Run `terraform apply` with the [`-parallelism=3`](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/apply#parallelism-n) option, which will instruct Terraform Core to not perform any more than three operations at once *across the entire configuration*.

  This could be a pragmatic, practical answer if this configuration is limited *only* to declaring these images, but will probably be undesirable if this is just a smaller part of a larger configuration because it will also prevent Terraform from performing more than three concurrent operations *regardless of object types*, and so `terraform apply` may take significantly longer to complete.